# Creating Pinterest like layout in ASP.NET webform

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, webforms, jquery-masonry, pinterest

I am creating a Pinterest like layout in ASP.NET webform and I followed following two tutorials

- [Creating Pinetrest like Layout in ASP.NET](http://techbrij.com/asp-net-pinterest-infinite-scroll-jquery-masonry)
- [How to use Masonry](http://www.ashlinixon.com/2012/09/how-to-create-a-pinterest-style-grid-with-jquery-masonry/)

However, I made changes in the first tutorial based on second and I am getting below output

[image]

Clearly, this isn't what I was looking. The gap between two rows and columns is high.

Below is my code:

<

```
style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            background-color:#EEEEEE;
        }
        #imgLoad
        {
            position:fixed;
            bottom:0;   
            left:40%;
            display:none;
        }
               .item {
  width: 220px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color:honeydew;
}
    </style>


 <div id="container" class="transitions-enabled infinite-scroll clearfix">
       <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <div class="item">
                   <img src="<%# Eval("Url") %>" />
                   <p><%# Eval("Description") %></p>
               </div>
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
   </div>
```

How do I fix it?
I believe this is related to the height, may be the row height of repeater control takes the highest among the column.

I did tried to do it with ASp.NET MVC

**Controller**

```
IEnumerable<Product> model = ProductRepository.GetData(1, 25);

            return View(model);
```

**View**

```
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <style type="text/css">


        .item {
  width: 220px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  background-color:honeydew;
}

    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Mansory.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $container = $('#container');

        $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
            $container.masonry({
                itemSelector: '.item',
                columnWidth: 100,
                isAnimated: false
            });
        });

    </script>




@foreach (var item in Model) {

     <div class="item">

        <img src="@(item.Url)" />
                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
    </div>


}
```

but same result

[image]

**EDIT 1**
I have changed my script to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var $container = $('#container');

            $container.masonry({
                itemSelector: '.item',
                columnWidth: 240,
                isAnimated: false
            });
        });


    </script>
```

and code to

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <div id="container">
     <div class="item">

        <img src="@(item.Url)" />
                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
    </div>

</div>
}
```

but same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, a few things:

- You have spelled "Masonry" wrong when initializing the script
- Put a div with Id "container" around your items list
- In stead of using `$container.imagesLoaded` make the whole javascript section run when page is loaded

Like this:

```
$(function(){ 
    var $container = $('#container');

    $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.item',
            columnWidth: 240,
            isAnimated: false
    });
});
```

Then it should work.

Comment: Please check Edit 1 section in my question. I made the changes but I am still facing the issue

Comment: Did you fix the problem where your masonry.js is named "Scripts/Mansory.js"?

Comment: Yes I downloaded from the official website I kept the same name now


<script src="~/Scripts/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>

Comment: I can see responsiveness and dynamic arrangement. I think height is the issue. I can see that each row is taking the maximum height from it's column.. just a guess

Comment: No, height should have nothing to do with it. It looks like you have described because the masonry script is not run. Check using FireBug or a similar tool if there are any errors logged to console.

Comment: And another thing: The container div should be OUTSIDE the foreach loop. Otherwise there will be one added per item.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'masonry'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37688/discussion-between-nicklas-forss-and-zerotoinfinite)

Answer (score 0):

This is small library which implements Pinterest layout. Filling the grid goes from left to right. Count of columns can be customized in config for each resolution. Columns adaptive changes on resize. Image can be at up or down of pin.

https://github.com/yury-egorenkov/pins-grid